# Animation in SMIL

Tags: html, smil

Does anyone have resources for learning animation in SMIL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These should get you going:

- [W3Schools SVG Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp)
- [Hefty tutorial](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~media/SMIL/Tutorial/SMILTut.html) along with [66 page PDF tutorial](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lynda/tue-2R480/SMILTut.pdf)
- [Animating in SVG using SMIL](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_smil.html)
- [A great resource from KevLinDev](http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/index.htm)
- [Introduction to SMIL](http://wdvl.com/Authoring/Languages/XML/SMIL/Intro/)
- and obviously [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language) and the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/)

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't like to learn from source, however [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-SMIL3-20081201/smil-animation.html) should be fine.